# HP Scanning UI for a Mac

Tags: mac, printer, scanner

I'm frustrated because I used to be able to type in "HP" on my application bar on my Mac (`Command-spacebar`), and a UI which I had installed 3 months ago would come up.  It had an awesome interface for scanning multiple pages from my Deskjet 3632 and saving them for example as a single PDF.

Well, it's gone, perhaps because of an upgrade in my Mac, and I don't know what the name of it was.  I would probably recognize it if I saw it but trying "HP Printer Scanning software for Mac" and etc. is not getting it.  And the one app in the mac store is rated at like 2 stars, and does not look like it.  Can anyone tell me a) what is the software name and b) if it might be still on my system and I'm missing it, and how to find it?  Thanks.

-- update --
this link does NOT work:
https://www.methodshop.com/2013/12/hp-utility-install.shtml
It loses me when it suggests I add a printer, not choose AirPrint, and then select the software - none of the combinations I try work.  Please help!

-- update --
someone suggested opening Apps.  I don't know how to open Apps :) But in the applications *folder* I definitely don't see HP
[image]

Comment: HP Easy Scan. Open Apps, type HP & it's next down, below the HP folder. Then see http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/17/rebuild-spotlight-index/ to reindex spotlight.

Comment: Thanks, but clicking on the Applications folder, using Launcher - NOTHING shows it nor does just a plain search for "HP" in finder.  And looking at reviews for HP Easy Scan in the App Store, there are 45 1star reviews and only a few 4 star.  This is something gone wrong - def. not installing HP Easy Scan on my machine!

Comment: Never had an issue with HP Easy Scan; it does what it says on the tin, from any computer in the building :) I don't have that printer though, so the suite may be different. I just ran the HP Setup app from their site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an OfficeJet Pro 8600 and find Apple's Image Capture app to be a full-featured scanning interface. Here's a screen capture:

[image]

Give it a try.

Comment: Curious what happens after you click `Scan`.  Does it give you a choice between "Scan another page" and "Done" ?  Thanks for this suggestion BTW!

Comment: If you use the document feeder, it will keep scanning.  When I use the flatbed, it's usually a single doc, so I don't recall the behavior.  Try it!